# How to get attribute value from xml parser - Android

Tags: java, android

Sample xml

```
<item>
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[ <img src="http://lorem.ipsum.com/lib/sample.jpg" align="left" hspace="5" width="100"/>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet........ ]]> 
    </description>
    <date>....</date>
</item>
```

how to get src value from img tag section using XMLPullParser? 
i'm using this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) to extract text values.

Comment: you can't ... `img` tag is not a part of xml as it is stored as character data ... you could try to parse the value of the `description` but it doesn't look like a valid xml ...

Comment: I need image source url, but parsing value not contain any tags just plain text. Is there any other way to extract all the characters or tags ? @Selvin

Answer (score 1):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory fectory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = fectory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(("<data>" + "here get ur description tag:eg. messages.get(i).getDescription()" + "</data>").getBytes("UTF-8"));
Document document = builder.parse(inputStream);
String imageURL = document.getElementsByTagName("img").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Selvin tells, the `<img>` part is not properly a part of the XML itself, because it is escapped within a CDATA section (making this a strange XML, by he way).

The easiest thing you could do is to get the `description` node through a first parsing. Then, get its text value, and parse it *with a second parser*, and then read the attributes.

This is just a first approach: You must first ensure:

- That the `description` content is a well-formed XML. If not, this approach is useless.
- That the `description` contains *just one* XML node. If not, you must enclose it within a dummy root node before the second parsing:

  String newXml="< root >"+cdataContent+"< /root >";